# ETIMEDOUT error on wikidata api call using request promise

Tags: node.js, api, wikidata

Below is the snippet of `nodejs` to call `wikidata api` using `request-promise` module

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

var wikidataURL="http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&props=labels|claims&languages=en&format=json&ids=Q1"

    let promise=rp(wikidataURL).catch(function(e){
      console.log(e);
    });
```

For me, it worked normally till `27/1/2020`. After that I get a `ETIMEDOUT connection` error. The same links would work on browser but not on `nodejs`. There is no proxy involved.

Error message:

```
   { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 91.198.174.192:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '91.198.174.192',
     port: 80 },
```

Is this something on my side or wikidata server?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems only https is allowed now for wikidata api query after some update from their side